# How to go about recording a livestream in python

Tags: python-3.x, video-streaming, live-streaming

I'm trying to write a python script to record and save segments of a live stream for research purposes. I know how to do it for mainstream platforms such as YouTube, but I'm not sure how to do it on this site.

Here's the video link:
http://cwwp2.dot.ca.gov/vm/loc/d3/hwy80atdonnersummit.htm

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Its not "recording" a video its just downloading. That site uses HLS. Any HLS downloader should work. But you need to get the URL form the m3u8 file.

Start by viewing the network tab of the browser, and the sites source code, You can then see how the browser plays it, then develop your script from that.